# iOS MarketingCloudSDK -v 8.0.13 and SFMCSDK -v1.08 - App Crash

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios

We are currently using **iOS** **MarketingCloudSDK -v8.1.3** and **SFMCSDK -v1.08** and **SFMCKeychainItemWrapper** has caused quite a few crashes. I have attached a Bugsnag code snippet for your review.

```
Hardware Model:     iPhone14,5
Role:               Background
OS Version:         iOS 16.5.1

com.salesforce.security.keychainException: setObject:forKey:: Error saving value to the keychain: errSecInteractionNotAllowed.

0  CoreFoundation +0x9cb4         ___exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib +0x183cc       _objc_exception_throw
2  SFMCSDK +0x103d4               +[SFMCKeychainItemWrapper logAndThrowKeychainItemExceptionWithCode:msg:] (SFMCKeychainItemWrapper.m:165:9)
3  SFMCSDK +0x10bdc               -[SFMCKeychainItemWrapper setObject:forKey:] (SFMCKeychainItemWrapper.m:307:17)
4  SFMCSDK +0x114d8               -[SFMCKeychainItemWrapper setValueData:] (SFMCKeychainItemWrapper.m:486:16)
5  SFMCSDK +0x9274                +[SFMCCrypto setDeviceBaseAppIdentifier:] (SFMCCrypto.m:250:26)
6  SFMCSDK +0x90f8                +[SFMCCrypto deviceBaseAppIdentifier] (SFMCCrypto.m:221:40)
7  SFMCSDK +0xd734                -[SFMCKeyStore buildUniqueKeychainId:] (SFMCKeyStore.m:143:27)
8  SFMCSDK +0xe460                -[SFMCGeneratedKeyStore keyStoreKey] (SFMCGeneratedKeyStore.m:82:59)
9  SFMCSDK +0x7d18                -[SFMCKeyStoreManager initializeKeyStores] (SFMCKeyStoreManager.m:131:32)
10 SFMCSDK +0x77d4                -[SFMCKeyStoreManager init] (SFMCKeyStoreManager.m:57:9)
11 SFMCSDK +0x7780                __37+[SFMCKeyStoreManager sharedInstance]_block_invoke (SFMCKeyStoreManager.m:48:21)
12 libdispatch.dylib +0x3ea8      __dispatch_client_callout
13 libdispatch.dylib +0x56e8      __dispatch_once_callout
14 SFMCSDK +0x7768                _dispatch_once (once.h:85:3)
15 SFMCSDK +0x3dad8               EncryptionManager.init(moduleName:) (EncryptionManager.swift:19:45)
16 SFMCSDK +0x49114               SFMCSdkComponents.init(moduleConfiguration:) (<compiler-generated>)
17 SFMCSDK +0x4935c               @objc ModuleInitializer.main() (<compiler-generated>)
18 SFMCSDK +0x20188               BaseOperation.start() (BaseOperation.swift:106:9)
19 Foundation +0x3c208            ___NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__
20 Foundation +0x41898            ___NSOQSchedule_f
21 libdispatch.dylib +0x12fc0     __dispatch_block_async_invoke2
22 libdispatch.dylib +0x3ea8      __dispatch_client_callout
23 libdispatch.dylib +0x732c      __dispatch_continuation_pop
24 libdispatch.dylib +0x6994      __dispatch_async_redirect_invoke
25 libdispatch.dylib +0x15940     __dispatch_root_queue_drain
26 libdispatch.dylib +0x16154     __dispatch_worker_thread2
27 libsystem_pthread.dylib +0xd9c __pthread_wqthread
28 libsystem_pthread.dylib +0xb78 _start_wqthread
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of accessing the Keychain when the device is setup with FaceId or Passcode based authentication and The SDK cannot access these files due to the iOS Data Protection mode.

Please set `SFMCSdk.setKeychainAccessErrorsAreFatal(errorsAreFatal: false)` before initializing the SDK.

The above logs the exception to console instead of crashing the application.